# Does strong duality holds when strong duality hold with respect to other variable form?

Tags: convex-optimization, entropy, duality-theorems

my question comes from Ziebart's thesis.

The theorem what I want to prove is Thm 5.8 from his thesis as following:

[image]

[image]

$E_{P(X^T,Y^T)}[F(X,Y)] = c \quad \quad \quad $for some function F and given c

where $H(Y^T||X^T) = E_{X^T,Y^T}[\Sigma_t-log P(Y_t|X_{1:t},Y_{1:t-1})]$ and $P(X^T,Y^T) =   \Pi_t P(Y_t|X_{1:t},Y_{1:t-1})P(X_t|X_{1:t-1},Y_{1:t-1})$ satisfies.

Also, $P(X_t|X_{1:t-1},Y_{1:t-1}) $ is given. And $Y^T=[Y_1,Y_2,...Y_T], X^T=[X_1,X_2,...X_T], X_{1:t} = [X_1,..X_t], Y_{1:t} = [Y_1, .. Y_t]$

**what I want to show is that that above problem is convex optimization and when slater's condition holds, strong duality holds.**

And the proof is given in the Ziebart's thesis.
He said that we can see the problem as a function of $P(Y^T||X^T) = \Pi_t P(Y_t|X_{1:t},Y_{1:t-1})$.

Then the formation becomes as following:

[image]
[image]

$E_{P(X^T,Y^T)}[F(X,Y)] = c$

The second constraint appears to satisfy $P(Y^T||X^T) = \Pi_t P(Y_t|X_{1:t},Y_{1:t-1})$.

Now, Ziebart said that the second problem is a convex problem and strong duality holds with respect to $P(Y^T||X^T)$ because the objective is convex and all constraints are affine. And the proof ends.

But what we want to know is if the first problem with respect to $P(Y_t|X_{1:t},Y_{1:t-1})$ satisfies the theorem.

**So, can I conclude the problem is a convex problem and strong duality holds if the equivalent but with respect to the other(may be substituted) variable is a convex problem and strong duality holds??**